# Sequelize create instance with association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In Sequelize 4, Have two classes: `User` and `Profile`, where they are associated by

```
User.associate = (model) => {
    User.hasMany(model.profile);
}
```

Now I have a instance of User named `user`, and want to create a instance of `Profile`, how can I create it with association to `user`.

Here is what I tried. It works but I am looking for a better solution.

```
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
Profile.create({userId: user.id})
```

Here is another way I trid but not work:

```
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
Profile.create({user: user},{include: User})
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

well, this helped:

```
var profile = new Profile();
profile.setUser(user);
Profile.create(profile).then(res.send('success'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create (or build and save) both your profile and your user instances. setUser on the profile. Save the profile (again).

Something like this:

```
const profile = Profile.build({...});
profile.save();

const user = User.build({...});
user.save();

profile.setUser(user);

profile.save();
```

In practice with promises it might look more like this after building a newUser and profile:

```
newUser.save().catch(err => console.log('Failed to create user', err))

profile.save()
.then(profile => profile.setUser(user))
.then(profile => profile.save())
.then(profile => {
  res.json(profile)
})
.catch(err => console.log('Failed to create profile', err));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
User.associate = (model) => {
    User.hasMany(model.profile, as "profile");
}
```

then

```
User.create({user: user, profile:profile},{include: Profile, as : "profile"})
```